# Logical test of a single symbol against multiple values

Tags: programming, logic

I'm currently trying a function that behaves differently depending on what kind of Type string you enter. This string can have six different values, let's say "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" and "F". What I want to construct is an if statement of the form

```
f[Type_]:=
     If[Type!="A"||"B"||"C"||"D",
          1,
          0
     ]
```

So basically this is a function that yields the value 0 if I enter types "A" through "D" but 1 for the two remaining types "E" and "F".

The problem with the above code is that this apparently is not the right way to make a multiple comparison for the function string Type.

> Note, I know about the Switch[] function, but this is nog sufficient for my case.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop".  Looping means repetition.  What does `If` repeat?  `Or`  (i.e. `||`) connects a series of statements, each of which can be true or false.  Thus this use is incorrect.  The simplest solution is `Switch` because it uses patterns and you can use `Alternatives`.  Don't simply just state that "Switch is not sufficient", explain *why*.

Comment: perhaps `MemberQ[{"A","B","C","D"},Type]` will do

Comment: @george2079 But it will always be slower than pattern matching like `Switch[Type,
 "A" | "B" | "C" | "D", 0,
 _, 1
 ]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, That actually solves my problem! My idea was that switch only took a function value depending on one argument, not multiple! Your comment is for me an answer. Is it perhaps possible to elaborate on how this switch statement works ?

Comment: These methods are alternative ways to achieve the same goal, but if you really wanted to use `Or` for the sake of understanding how things work you could make several complete statements chained together: `(Type=="A"||Type=="B"||..)`.  Which you can do with:  `Or@@Thread[Equal[Type,{"A","B","C","D"}]]`

Comment: `Switch` will test an expression against the patterns you give, one by one, and find the first one that matches.  Then it evaluates the corresponding expression.  `|` is `Alternatives`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple but robust solution to this problem is to use multiple definitions.

```
f["A" | "B" | "C" | "D"] = 0;
f["E" | "F"] = 1;
f[___] = $Failed;
```

Then

```
f /@ CharacterRange["A", "H"]
```

gives

> `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $Failed, $Failed}`

Comment: Looks like an elegant solution! What does the f[type: ...] do exactly? I always assumed that f[x_]:= was the way to go for functional arguments?

Comment: @Dominique, Good question! It doesn't do anything. I mindlessly copied it from your question. Not only is `type` not needed, but `SetDelayed` can be replace by a simple `Set`. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: OK, now I fully understand the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Some variants:

```
f[x_] := 1 - Boole[Or @@ (x == # & /@ CharacterRange["A", "D"])]
g[x_] := Boole[And @@ (x != # & /@ CharacterRange["A", "D"])]
h[x_] := x /. {(Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A", "D"]) :> 0, 
   s_ :> 1}
```

e.g

```
test = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 20];
TableForm[{#, f@#, g@#, h@#} & /@ test, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "f", "g", "h"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice addition! I'll remember this one!